# Error with insertSource(): "object '.cacheOnAssign' not found"

Tags: r, package

I am trying to use the function `insertSource` (new in R 2.12) to update a function that I have made changes on.

However, when I use the function in this way:

```
insertSource('filename.R', package = 'mypackage')
```

I get the error:

```
Error in get(this, envir = envp) : object '.cacheOnAssign' not found
```

Unfortunately I can not come up with a simple reproducible example - if one would be helpful, please suggest how I can do it - but I have found that the following code does work:

```
system("echo 'nls <- function(nls) return(nls)' > foo.R")
insertSource('foo.R', package = stats)
```

One difference between the stats package and mypackage is the library location (mypackage is in '~/lib/R/'. (*update*): error still occurs when `.libPaths('~/lib/R')` is in `.Rprofile`, and googleing '.cacheOnAssign' only returns 6 hits, two of them to this question.

### Questions:

1. what does the error mean?
2. How can I use `insertSource`?

#### Debugging

using `options(error = recover)`

```
options(error = recover) 
Error in get(this, envir = envp) : object '.cacheOnAssign' not found
Called from: get(this, envir = envp)
Browse[1]> where
where 1: get(this, envir = envp)
where 2: insertSource("filename.R", "mypackage")
Browse[1]> ls()
[1] "q"
Browse[1]> n
>
```

not sure what to make of these results, and where to go from here

using `options(error = browser)` gives more information that I have placed in a [text file](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18092793/seerror.txt)

Comment: Try setting `options(error = recover)` or `options(error = browser)` and seeing if you can find the exact point where it falls over.

Comment: The `bugger` function also helps with this. http://4dpiecharts.com/2010/09/04/oh-debugger-part-ii/

Comment: This question went unanswered for awhile, and yet I'm having the same issue, so I'll put a bounty on it, rather than produce a duplicate question.

Comment: @David By the way, did you get any further on this?  [XKCD:979 - "Who were you DenverCoder9?  What did you see?!"](http://xkcd.com/979/)

Comment: @Iterator I was not able to get any further, and ended up dropping the use of this function.

Comment: @David Thanks.  I'm glad you wrote up the problem & the questions so clearly.  Fortunately, I think Simon has now resolved this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is arguably a bug in `insertSource()`. When you supply a file instead of an environment, it calls `evalSource()` on the file which synthesizes the `.cacheOnAssign` variable (it will be simply `FALSE`) in the source environment. That chokes the replacement since the variable does not necessarily exist in the package namespace.

There are several ways around this, probably the easiest is to create the environment yourself and remove `.cacheOnAssign` like in this fix:

```
insertSource <- function(source, package="", ...) {
    if (!is(source, "environment")) {
        source <- evalSource(source, package = package, lock = FALSE)
        rm(.cacheOnAssign, envir = source)
    }
    methods::insertSource(source, package = package, ...)
}
```

Comment: FWIW I have added a fix to R-devel

Comment: Golly, a good fix in R-devel, too?  Quite an overachiever - that's more than adequate for a mere 50 rep bounty.  :)  That'll be hard to top for anyone else on SO.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to solve this without yielding to `bugger`, and I think I have.  :)

I am not sure what the error message means, but it is uninformative and possibly undocumented, which means that it is useless to me.  In any case, my goal was to solve the issue of using `insertSource` rather than to figure out the meaning of this error.

It turns out that one needs to specify the `functions` argument in `insertSource()`.  Here's a generic version of how I got it to work:

```
# Specify the new source file and the package to be updated
tmpFname <- "mySource.R"
myPkgName <- "myPkg"

# Load the package - it might not already be loaded
do.call(library, list(myPkgName))

# We need to know which functions are going to be produced, so we run `evalSource()`
tmpEval <- evalSource(tmpFname, package = myPkgName)

# Not everything from `evalSource()` is a function, so omit that stuff
newFuncs <- ls(tmpEval)[-match(c("packageName", "sourceFile"), ls(tmpEval))]

# Now, we can submit a proper incantation to `insertSource()`
insertSource(tmpFname, package = myPkgName, functions = newFuncs)
```

The output is then:

```
Modified functions inserted through trace():  (... my functions here ...)
```

I hope this works for others.  The documentation for `insertSource()` and `evalSource()` could use some work.

---

Note 1.  Although I think I've addressed the goal of using `insertSource()`, the bounty remains in place.  Answering David's 2 original questions (i.e. what does the error mean, and what are these functions really doing & how should the be used), would suffice.  I'm not able to answer the error question, nor do I have much familiarity of the arguments/parameters to `evalSource` and `insertSource`.